# JavaScript for-loop with if and if not statment to display only the current item, and hide all the other

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to make this work... it need to switch between display = "block" and display = "none".

if the verifyer is true display block
if the verifyer is false display none

It works in my console Log..

HTML

```html
<button id="knapOne">knap</button>
<button id="knapTwo">knap</button>

<p id="demo">hej</p>
<p id="anotherDemo">hej igen</p>
```

Javascript:

```js
var verifyer = null;
var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
var anotherDemo = document.getElementById("anotherDemo");

document.getElementById("knapOne").onclick = function(){
  verifyer = demo;
  change()
}

document.getElementById("knapTwo").onclick = function(){
  verifyer = anotherDemo;
  change()
}

function change(){
  var cars = [demo, anotherDemo];
  for (index = 0; index < cars.length; index++) {
    if(cars != verifyer){
      console.log("this is not the current car");
      cars.style.display = "none";
    }
    if(cars = verifyer){
      console.log("this is the current car");
      cars.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try cars[i] ;P that way you will actually select the correct array element. Your console shouldve thrown and error.

Comment: try `cars == verifyer` in the second if statement..

Comment: `index` (a number) is never going to equal `cars` (an array of Elements).

Comment: In my example i'm not trying to equal index and cars array. I'm simply trying to point at the same element. Which i just needed to select the correct array element as using cars[index] noa-dev and JJ173 shows in their examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example, it seems you're missing an index when trying to work with your array.

You need to make sure you're indexing so the loop can iterate through each element of your array:

```js
      for (index = 0; index < cars.length; index++) {
          if (cars[index] != verifyer){
                console.log("this is not the current car");
                cars[index].style.display = "none";
          } else if (cars[index] == verifyer){
                console.log("this is the current car");
                cars[index].style.display = "block";
          }
      }
```